# Split a column in pandas based on a number of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a column with text in pandas.

This column contains the words 'Alpha', 'Beta'. 
I need this column to be split after these words, these words and everything before need to go in one column and everything after this in a new column.

I tried this:

```
split_df = df.str.split('ALPHA ').apply(pd.Series)
```

But then I lose everything before ALPHA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex `r'Alpha|Beta'` - it means `Alpha` or `Beta`:

```
print df
             text
0   aaa Alpha bbb
1   ddd Alpha ccc
2    uuu Beta vvv

split_df = df['text'].str.split(r'Alpha|Beta').apply(pd.Series)
split_df.columns = ['before','after']
print split_df
  before  after
0   aaa     bbb
1   ddd     ccc
2   uuu     vvv
```